# Color of Notification Icon in android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-5.0-lollipop, android-drawable

Sometime back when I upgraded to lolipop on my Moto E the small notification icon turned black and white(I read that its the new google guidline). SO Ok I can live with it.
Now I have noticed that the icon has turned color again, and I havent changed my code and have been using the same drawable. It sure was showing black and white and now its colored.
My device is on Android 5.0.2
Also:

```
 compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
 targetSdkVersion 22
```

Here is my code:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 })
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);
```

Can anybody tell me how this happened?

Comment: which target api / build tools were / are you using?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" and  targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: It also depends on the drawables, post them as well somehow. Although the B/W is recommended, you can use colors in the drawables. Besides the "logo" as a notification icon is suspicious as well, looks like your launcher icon might have mixed in there

Comment: the drawable(logo) is just a colored png file. Earlier also I was using the same file and the notification icon was coming black and white

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that ever since the android upgraded to lolipop the small icon on the notification comes in black and white only...
but it can be changed with the `.setColor()` method as shown in the code below.

Here's the code to set the color of the notification icon:-

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appypie_small);
    notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
} 
else {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appypie_small);
}
```

Comment: When the app is in the background, the color is used that is specified in the android config of the message sent to the FCM endpoint. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification